# Append Textbox value to a string

Tags: c#, vb.net

In my code

```
 oOutputFile.FileName = "F:\inventor\Proof Of Con\Rim\Document\Rim_Update.dwf
```

I want to add textbox1  value to the end of the file name.here my textbox1 value  is 100.Then the output will look like

```
Rim_Update100.dwf
```

how can I add this

Comment: C# or VB, which language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
oOutputFile.FileName = "F:\inventor\Proof Of Con\Rim\Document\Rim_Update" & textbox1.Value & ".dwf"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `Path` class of `System.IO` to manipulate paths:

```
  System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(oOutputFile.FileName) + 
          textbox1.Text + 
          System.IO.Path.GetExtension(oOutputFile.FileName)
```